# HashSet in Powershell: Collection was of a fixed size

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a **PowerShell** function as follows:

```
Function GetAllIdentityProvidersFromDatabase {

    param (
        [string] $SQLConnectionSting
    )

    $AllIdPIdentifiers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
    $SQLConnect = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection $SQLConnectionSting

    try {
        $SQLQuery = $("SELECT [IdPIdentifier] FROM [dbo].[IdPs]")


        $SQLConnect.Open()  

        $command = New-object system.data.sqlclient.SqlCommand   
        $command.connection = $SQLConnect  
        $command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
        $Reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
        while ($Reader.Read()) {
            $value = $Reader.GetValue($1)
            $AllIdPIdentifiers.Add($value) | Out-Null
        }

        $AllIdPIdentifiers

    } catch {
        Write-Host "SQL Select error: " $Error[0].ToString() -ForegroundColor Red
    } finally {
        $SQLConnect.Close()
    }
}
```

Then, in another script:

```
$AllIdPIdentifiers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
$AllIdPIdentifiers = GetAllIdentityProvidersFromDatabase $SQLConnectionString
$AllIdPIdentifiers.Remove("GodspeedYou")
Write-Host $AllIdPIdentifiers.Count
```

And by executing it, I have this error:

```
Exception calling "Remove" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At C:\PowerShell\EduGain\FederationMetadataExtractor.ps1:151 char:1
+ $AllIdPIdentifiers.Remove("GodspeedYou")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

Is there a way to allow the `Remove` operation?

Comment: `GetAllIdentityProvidersFromDatabase` return not `HashSet` but `string`s, which would be packed into array, if more than one. And arrays are fixed size.

Comment: @PetSerAl: assuming you're correct, it would be helpful if you'd elaborate on _why_ the function is returning an array of `string` objects. Given that the function appears to evaluate to the value of `$AllIdPIdentifiers`, and that references a `HashSet<T>` object, my naïve reading of the code is that the function itself would return the `HashSet<T>` object. Is there a way to get a PowerShell function to return an actual `HashSet<T>` object, if not the code the OP has shown?

Comment: Is it not possible to populate an HashSet instead of an Array by using the returned value of my function? It is in order to use a data structure that minimizes the effort on `Contains` and `Remove` operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass collection by pipeline, it is enumerated and each individual element is passed. If you want to pass collection as single element, you should pack collection to another collection. Unary `,` create array with single element.

```powershell
Function GetAllIdentityProvidersFromDatabase {

    param (
        [string] $SQLConnectionSting
    )

    $AllIdPIdentifiers = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]'
    $SQLConnect = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection $SQLConnectionSting

    try {
        $SQLQuery = $("SELECT [IdPIdentifier] FROM [dbo].[IdPs]")


        $SQLConnect.Open()  

        $command = New-object system.data.sqlclient.SqlCommand   
        $command.connection = $SQLConnect  
        $command.CommandText = $SQLQuery
        $Reader = $command.ExecuteReader()
        while ($Reader.Read()) {
            $value = $Reader.GetValue($1)
            $AllIdPIdentifiers.Add($value) | Out-Null
        }

        ,$AllIdPIdentifiers

    } catch {
        Write-Host "SQL Select error: " $Error[0].ToString() -ForegroundColor Red
    } finally {
        $SQLConnect.Close()
    }
}
```