# PowerShell function will not return DataTable

Tags: powershell, datatable

I've got a PowerShell script on PowerShell v4.0 (Windows 7 x64 SP1) that creates a pretty complex DataTable.  I wanted to be able to place that DataTable code anywhere pretty easily, so I decided to wrap it in a simple function, like so:

```
function Get-UserDataTable
{
    $DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable -ArgumentList 'User';

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('Id',[System.Int32]);
    $NewColumn.AllowDBNull = $false;
    $NewColumn.Unique = $true;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('FirstName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('MiddleName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('LastName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    return $DataTable;
}
```

However, that code always returns a null object.  I tried `Write-Output $DataTable`, `return $DataTable.Copy()`, and `$DataTable`, but the function is still always null.

So, I thought I might try adding some rows.  I can always clear the DataTable, and it'd still be less coding this way:

```
function Get-UserDataTable2
{
    $DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable -ArgumentList 'User';

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('Id',[System.Int32]);
    $NewColumn.AllowDBNull = $false;
    $NewColumn.Unique = $true;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('FirstName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('MiddleName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('LastName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewRow = $DataTable.NewRow();
    $NewRow.Id = 1;
    $NewRow.FirstName = 'Test';
    $NewRow.MiddleName = '';
    $NewRow.LastName = 'User';

    $DataTable.Rows.Add($NewRow);

    $NewRow = $DataTable.NewRow();
    $NewRow.Id = 2;
    $NewRow.FirstName = 'Other';
    $NewRow.MiddleName = 'Test';
    $NewRow.LastName = 'User';

    $DataTable.Rows.Add($NewRow);

    return $DataTable;
}
```

Nope.  This function returns a `[System.Object[]]` containing individual `[System.Data.DataRow]`.  An object array of DataRows.

How can I return a DataTable from a function in PowerShell?

Comment: `return ,$DataTable;`. `DataTable` considered as collection, although it does not implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HashSet in Powershell: Collection was of a fixed size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148260/hashset-in-powershell-collection-was-of-a-fixed-size)

Comment: @PetSerAl `return ,$DataTable;` appears to work.  Totally forgot about that.  Enter as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Ok, so, thinking about it some, the *answer* is the same in the duplicate, but it's *not* the same question.  "Duplicate" means "Duplicate *question*", not duplicate answer.

Comment: From my point of view, the only practical difference between the questions is the collection type `HashSet` vs `DataTable`. Rest is the same: you return collection from function and do not see that collection, but individual collection elements packed into array. If you disagree, feel free to answer question by your own answer or find a better duplicate question to close.

Comment: Well, the problem is you didn't explain that, so when I read the other question and thought, "This isn't the question I'm asking." I said it wasn't a dupe.  Now I *can't* accept it as a dupe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the link in PerSerAl's comment suggests, the issue is caused because DataTable isn't an enumerable data type.  To force it to be enumerable, you can use the unary comma operator to put it into an array as a single element.  Arrays *are* enumerable.

```
function Get-UserDataTable
{
    $DataTable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable -ArgumentList 'User';

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('Id',[System.Int32]);
    $NewColumn.AllowDBNull = $false;
    $NewColumn.Unique = $true;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('FirstName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('MiddleName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    $NewColumn = $DataTable.Columns.Add('LastName',[System.String]);
    $NewColumn.MaxLength = 64;

    return ,$DataTable;
}
```

Comment: The solution is effective, but the explanation isn't quite correct: you're not forcing it to be enumerable, you're _preventing its enumeration_, by using the unary form of `,` to create a transient single-element wrapper array. The background is that - unfortunately - PowerShell has a hard-coded exception that treats `[System.Data.DataTable]` _as if_  it implemented the `IEnumerable` interface, even though it doesn't. Specifically, using such an instance in the PowerShell pipeline is equivalent to using its `.Rows` property (which returns a collection type that does implement `IEnumerable`).

Answer (score 0):

> This question seem like a [duplicate for this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495766/how-to-return-specific-data-type-from-powershell-function-i-e-datatable), but you may want to look at the more elaborative info on [that answer & below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495766/how-to-return-specific-data-type-from-powershell-function-i-e-datatable#answer-39496461).