# How to return specific data type from PowerShell function i.e. DataTable

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to write a utility function that will return initialized `[System.Data.DataTable]` object data type.

I am aware of the **annoying PowerShell functions return behavior** where it tries to "unroll" everything into a `[System.Array]` return type. 
Previously I have always managed to get around that problem. 
Usually using the "comma trick" to return your own array `@(,$result)` aways worked - however this time this does not seem to make a difference and I've run out of options...

Another trick I normally use is the `$null` assignments within the Process block (see my code bellow) - this way I fool the pipeline there is nothing to "unroll" on the output...

I am not taking impossible for an answer, so far based on my experience nothing is impossible in PowerShell :)

Here is my code:

```
function Get-SourceDataTable 
{
    [OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy] $Destination,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] $ColumnDefinition,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [int]$ColumnStartIndex = 0
    )
    BEGIN{
        $datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $colIndex = $ColumnStartIndex 
    }
    PROCESS{
        $ColumnDefinition.Keys | 
        foreach {
            $null = $datatable.Columns.Add($_, $ColumnDefinition[$_])   # define each column name and data type
            $null = $Destination.ColumnMappings.Add($_, $colIndex) # map column to destination table
            $colIndex++
        }
    }
    END{
        return ,$datatable
    }
}
```

I hope someone can get this code working...

Comment: Have you tried just casting the output as a DataTable? `[system.data.datatable]$MyVar = Get-SourceDataTable $Dest $ColDef`

Comment: Yes, I tried a casting it does not seem to have an effect on the output type

Comment: I've had the same problem. This is ridiculous to have to jump through all these hoops to get a function to return the data type you're already telling it to return. A function should ALWAYS return the data type specified, not a different type of object. If I wanted to return an array then I would write my function to return an array.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rather than `return` use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate`.    For example:

```
function New-DataTable {
   $datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
   $null = $datatable.Columns.Add("x",[int])
   $null = $datatable.Columns.Add("y",[int])
   $null = $datatable.Rows.Add(@(1,2))
   $null = $dataTable.Rows.Add(@(3,4))
   Write-Output -NoEnumerate $datatable
}

New-DataTable | Get-Member
```

Note however that if you just type `New-DataTable`, it might *look* like enumberated rows, but `Get-Member` tells you the actual type returned.

Comment: Good question and good answer. After I up-voted the question and the answer many months ago, I encountered the issue again, since I forgot the answer, my google result took me back here again. Really wish I could up-vote it again. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I had fun answering it too.

Answer (score 7):

I got the function from the question to return `DataTable` type when I used `LoadWithPartialName` to load the assembly containing the type and pipe it out with `Out-Null`.

Don't ask me why, but feel free to comment if you know the reason.

The working function code is below. Note the return statement is not necessary I only use it to improve code readability:

```
function Get-SourceDataTable 
{
    [OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy] $Destination,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] $ColumnDefinition,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [int]$ColumnStartIndex = 0
    )
    BEGIN{
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data") | Out-Null
        $datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $colIndex = $ColumnStartIndex 
    }
    PROCESS{
        $ColumnDefinition.Keys | 
        foreach {
            $null = $datatable.Columns.Add($_, $ColumnDefinition[$_])   # define each column name and data type
            $null = $Destination.ColumnMappings.Add($_, $colIndex) # map column to destination table
            $colIndex++
        }
    }
    END{
        return ,$datatable
    }
}
```

To summarize all known possible solutions to the problem of forcing PowerShell function to return specific data type:

- use `$null` assignments
- use comma to return an array `,$variable`
- use `LoadWithPartialName("Assembly.Name") | Out-Null`
- use `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $variable` to return the type - credit goes to [Burt_Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776535/burt-harris)

Finally, after the input from [Burt_Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776535/burt-harris) (THANKS Burt!) the final working version of the function from this question is this:

```
function Get-SourceDataTable 
{
    [OutputType([System.Data.DataTable])]
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy] $Destination,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] $ColumnDefinition,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [int]$ColumnStartIndex = 0
    )
    BEGIN{
        #[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data") | Out-Null
        $datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $colIndex = $ColumnStartIndex 
    }
    PROCESS{
        $ColumnDefinition.Keys | 
        foreach {
            $null = $datatable.Columns.Add($_, $ColumnDefinition[$_])   # define each column name and data type
            $null = $Destination.ColumnMappings.Add($_, $colIndex) # map column to destination table
            $colIndex++
        }
    }
    END{
        #return ,$datatable
        Write-Output -NoEnumerate $datatable
    }
}
```