# how to loop through datatable in powershell?

Tags: sql, powershell, datatable

I am getting different errors while fetching data from datatable. Here is my code to fill datatable:

```
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dt.Columns.Add("ServiceName")
$dt.Columns.Add("HostName")

$SQLConnection.Open()
$Reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($Reader.Read()) {
    $dt.Rows.Add($Reader.GetValue(0), $Reader.GetValue(1))
}
$SqlConnection.Close()
return $dt
```

Above code is in a function which returns datatable and when I access this returned datatable in calling script I don't get the data.

Script to fetch data on each row:

```
foreach ($Row in $BackupData) {
    Write-Host "$Row[0]"
    Write-Host "$Row[1]"
}
```

I am getting output like:

```
ServiceName[0]
HostName[0]
System.Data.DataRow[0]
System.Data.DataRow[0]
System.Data.DataRow[0]
System.Data.DataRow[0]
```

And when I use `"$($Row[0])"` I get another error

> unable to index an object of type system.Data.DataColumn

How can I get the data of each row and column?

Comment: How about just `$BackupData`, or `$BackupData | Format-Table -AutoSize`?

Comment: foreach ($row in $dt)
 {
  write-host $row[0]
  write-host $row[1]
 } this works if do this in the function where the data is being filled but does not work with the same datatable  returned from that function.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using? There will be a`PSSnapin` or `Module` that can make this much easier.

Comment: [Maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39495766/1630171)?

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to fill a DataTable with the help of a SqlDataAdapter like so:

```
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter -ArgumentList $ConnectionString, $SqlQuery
$da.fill($dt)
```

So you don't have to take care of opening and closing a connection and using a SqlDataReader either.

All the rows are now part of the DataTable object $dt and can be accessed either with the row index and a specific field name

```
$dt[0].FieldName
```

where "FieldName" is the name of a field of that table. Or without having to know the name of a specific field

```
$dt.Row[0}[0]
```

The resason for the error is that you have to use a sub expression with Write-Host like so:

```
Write-Host "value of first field: $($Row[0])"
```

Comment: `$dt.Row[0}[0]` That can't be right - can it? Should it be `$dt.Row[0][0]` ?

Comment: Yes, $dt.Row[0][0], of course - first index for the row and the second for the field (thanks for pointing that out)