# Return Value of a function is not being assigned to the variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm new in PowerShell scripting and having a weird problem in returning value of a function and assigning it to a variable. Let's have a look:
I've a function called Testing in a module file

```
## FILE NAME MODULES.PSM1

Function Testing() {
    $a = "something"
    return $a
}
```

I want to assign the value of the function to the variable `$result`

```
#FILENAME SCRIPT.PS1 
Import-Module ".\module.psm1"
$result = Testing
```

and the expected output is

```
"something"
```

But my actual output is null. That means there's nothing assigned in the `$result` variable.

> ***** UPDATE *****

Another strange thing is, the module is not being reloaded even if I run the script. If I close the CLI and reopen and re-execute, it works. But after any modification, only the previous code executes.

The Only thing is function is defined in a module file, and the assignment is in the script file. The importing is working well with other functions.

Does anybody have any idea where did I fail? Is there any other way to assign the return value of a function to the variable in powershell or reload the module file?

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Unfortunately your minimal example doesn't allow to reproduce the problem. Can you be a little more specific, where you put what in your module?

Comment: In the module you are talking about, did you [Export-ModuleMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-6) the function `Testing`? Also, have a look at the [Verb-Noun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) convention for naming PowerShell functions.

Comment: As written this works. Suggest editing your question with a real problem or removing it altogether.

Comment: If `$a` is not an ienumerable data type (for example, a HashTable, DataTable, etc.) then it will not return anything.  You can use the unary comma operator to allow it to return.  In other words, try `return ,$a`.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491390/powershell-function-will-not-return-datatable) is a candidate duplicate question if my above comment is correct, but I'm not going to mark it as a possible dupe because there's nowhere near enough information here to tell.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. Well I found out that the problem is not with the code but with the module import. it's not being reloaded even while running the Import-Module command. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: If a module has been imported it is loaded into memory and changes made to it afterwards will not be applied. You can try to remove the module before importing it again: `Remove-Module YourModule` followed by `Import-Module YourModule`. Another thing you can try is to use the `-Force` on the `Import-Module` cmdlet.
By the way, you have never answered if your module includes the `Export-ModuleMember` so scripts importing the module can actually use your `Testing` function.